# imageView Scale is correct on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a different scale ImageView on my real device (phone) and emulator. The emulator displays the image correctly but the real device(phone) doesn't. The image becomes smaller on the device (phone) screen.

this is my java code :

```
...

rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.arabic_page, container, false);
waraka = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.waraka);
...
     InputStream istr;
            try {
//Search in OBB 
    istr = getExpansionFile().getInputStream(num_image+".png");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    Drawable draw =new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
    waraka.setImageDrawable(draw);
```

and this is my layout code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/waraka"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen?  The image to be the same relative size (relative within the layout)?

Answer (score 0):

You have "wrap_content" for both your layout_width and layout_height.  Depending on the dpi resolution of your phone, it will be different sizes.  You will have to specify the size in dps if you want a specific size to look relatively the same across multiple devices.
So change your image view to be:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/waraka"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read through this link thoroughly to understand different screen sizes: [Android Screens Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Likely what is happening is that your phone has a much higher screen density than the emulator which is why things are smaller.  Try using density-independent pixels (dp) in your layouts instead.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the emulator and the phone don't have the same screen resolution so you cannot be sure how much of the space would an image take in your layout unless you set it in dimension points (dp) so :

First: why you use both:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Second: I Think that this code will work for you :

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/waraka"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```